# Keep String Characters Prior to a Matched Pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to find all the occurrences of certain pattern and replace it with another text. However, I also need to add a single character before a text that occurs before the matched pattern. An example will clarify my intention; I need to convert the following piece:

```
listName != null && listName.size() > 0
```

to:

```
listName != null && !listName.isEmpty()
```

As you can see, not only I need to replace `size() > 0` with `isEmpty()`, I need to add `!` right before `listName` so the parser should read backward until it gets to a space or tab. I have tried the following but no luck,

```
[ (.*?)\size\(\) > 0]\1

!$1isEmpty()
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @devnull I am using Find/Replace feature of Eclipse which allegedly supports Regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this search replace:

```
pattern: (\S+?\.)size\(\) > 0\b
replacement: !$1isEmpty()
```

`\S` means all that is not a space and `+?` is a lazy quantifier which takes the minimum number of character until `.size()...`.

Comment: This pattern will not work for 
 if ((variants != null) && (variants.size() > 0)) {

Comment: @MarkusLausberg: indeed, fortunately it isn't the searched string.

Comment: A shame, i thought i can use it. Do you have a second version of the regular expresion? ;)